# For loop in R calculation wrong result

Tags: r, for-loop, random

I want to calculate the
`sum_{i}^{n} x_{i}^2 * lambda^(n-i) / sum_{i}^{n} lambda^(n-i)`

Doing so in R i manage to do the following.But zeros occured.What am i doing wrong?

```
n = 10
x = seq(1,n,1);x
lambda = 0.99 
mat = 0 
for (i in 2:n) {
  mat = (lambda^(n-i)*x[i-1]^2) /  (lambda^(n-i))
}
mat
```

the result must be the variance of each entry `x_{i}`

Comment: if the numerator returns 0, then that value becomes 0

Comment: *"variance of each entry"* ... variance of a single number should be undefined, never a real number. I suggest you [edit] this question and add `set.seed(42)` (or some int), run your code, and demonstrate what you expect at least the first so-many values of `mat` to be.

Comment: @r2evans i expect to have the ewmavol of MTS package but to create it by my own so if you do the ```MTS::EWMAvol(x,0.99)``` must be the wanted results

Comment: Thank you for adding `set.seed`. It seems like you want to reproduce the results of that function, which is fine ... but since I don't have `MTS` installed, I'm out. It should have been simple enough to *put some of that output in your question*, but if you prefer an answer to come from somebody who is familiar with the package, then so be it. Good luck!

Comment: FYI, your formula multiplies by `lambda^(n-i)` and then divides by the same number, so your formula reduces to `mat[i-1]^2`.

Comment: @r2evans i know [here](https://github.com/r-forge/mftsr/blob/master/pkg/R/ewmaVol.R) between  the lines 78 - 86 i that i want to reproduce but in an other way

Comment: fyi, you can link to a line or sequence of lines directly, see https://github.com/r-forge/mftsr/blob/master/pkg/R/ewmaVol.R#L78-L86

Comment: okay, but you are using `lambda` differently and omitting the `(1-lambda)` component of this. So what you need in the end is exponentially-weighted moving variance? When you say *"reproduce but in an other way"*, what do you mean? Is this an exercise for you to learn to code the same result? Are you just going for dependency-reduction for your code? Or are you trying to change the formula to calculate something completely different?

Comment: I want to learn to write it by my own and understand the mechanics of this ewma volatility

Comment: Try editing like this: `mat = mat + (lambda^(n-i)*x[i-1]^2) /  (lambda^(n-i))` in the appropriate line of your function.

Comment: @Diego and if I want to see how this progresses over n?How I can modify the for loop?

Comment: @The Red You could create an empty vector with `n-1` components (it goes from 2 to n) before the `for` loop and grab each `mat` variable as a component of the vector...  At the end of the loop you'd see what you need...

Comment: @Diego ```n = 10
numeric(n-1)
x = seq(1,n,1);x
lambda = 0.99 
mat = numeric(n-1)
for (i in 2:n) {
  mat = mat + (lambda^(n-i)*x[i-1]^2) /  (lambda^(n-i))
}
mat``` this is what I have understood but produces the same result repeatedly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very well, I will try to see if this is what you need @The Red:

```
n <-  10
x <-  seq(1,n,1);x
lambda <-  0.99 
mat <- 0
vect_mat <- rep(0, n-1); vect_mat
for (i in 2:n) {
  mat <-  mat + (lambda^(n-i)*x[i-1]^2) /  (lambda^(n-i))
  vect_mat[i-1] <- mat
}
mat
vect_mat
```

After running it, it results in:

```
> mat
[1] 285
> vect_mat
[1]   1   5  14  30  55  91 140 204 285
```